# Meteor multiple instances on App Engine / meteor-files

Tags: google-app-engine, meteor, multiprocessing, stateful

I deployed a meteor app on App Engine on one instance, it works well.

However, when I want to scale on two  instances, I sometimes got 401 on HTTP GET requests. Every call through websocket is **successful** with two instances.

**More details:**

I use meteor-files to handle upload and download.
When I download a file, the client makes an HTTP request (GET) to download the file from the server. In a method, I check *this.userId* (from the meteor) to compare it with the owner of the file (on mongoDb)

**with one instance**

- when the user is authenticated, it always works: *this.userId* is always set

**with two instances**

- when the client is authenticated with instance 1 AND the request is directed to instance 1 => OK
- when the client is authenticated with instance 1 AND the request is directed to instance **2** => *this.userId* is null.

**What I tried**

In app.yaml:

```
network: 
  session_affinity: true
```

However when I check the config in the google app engine service, I got:

```
network:{}
```

It seems to be related to this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154647126

**My questions**

- How do you handle mutli instances with Meteor ?
- How do you handle multi instances with Meteor in Google App Engine?

Thanks,

Comment: What storage so you use with Meteor-Files? s3, gridFs, Filesystem etc?

Comment: First it's stored on Filesystem then sent to a Google bucket.

Comment: Is the file succesfully uploaded to the server? Is the rest of your mongo db shared correctly across the apps?

Comment: Yes, the file id uploaded. On instance 1, I can download it. On instance 2, I got 401.
Yes, the db is correctly shared across the app.

Comment: Ah sorry I overread the part that on instance 2 the userId is null and 401 comes from the meteor files (protected function???) and not from the google bucket. I think this may be something you clarify with the package maintainer, he es very responsive to issues.